# How to unit test that my class listen to a stream and responds correctly in Dart

Tags: unit-testing, dart, stream

Consider the following class:

```
enum LoginState { loggedOut, loggedIn }

class StreamListener {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth;
  LoginState _state = LoginState.loggedOut;

  LoginState get state => _state;

  StreamListener({required FirebaseAuth auth}) : _auth = auth {
    _auth.userChanges().listen((user) {
      if (user != null) {
        _state = LoginState.loggedIn;
      } else {
        _state = LoginState.loggedOut;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

I would like to test that when a user login the state changes from loggedOut to loggedIn, see the following test code:

```
class FakeUser extends Fake implements User {}

@GenerateMocks([FirebaseAuth])
void main() {
  StreamController<User?> controller = StreamController<User?>();
  final User value = FakeUser();

  setUp(() {
    controller = StreamController.broadcast();
  });

  tearDown(() {
    controller.close();
  });

  test('Stream listen test', () {
    final MockFirebaseAuth mockAuth = MockFirebaseAuth();
    when(mockAuth.userChanges()).thenAnswer((_) => controller.stream);
    StreamListener subject = StreamListener(auth: mockAuth);

    controller.add(value);

    expect(subject.state, LoginState.loggedIn);
  });
}
```

However, due to the async behaviour the login state is still loggedOut. How could I test this properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that you can test that in a way that is strictly correct.  Your `StreamListener` class promises to update `state` in response to `Stream` events, but it's asynchronous, you have no formal guarantee when those updates might happen, and you have no way to notify callers when those updates eventually do occur.  You could solve that by modifying `StreamListener` to provide a broadcast `Stream<LoginState>` that is emitted whenever `_state` changes.

From a practical perspective of being good enough, there are a few things you could do:

- Rely on Dart's event loop to invoke all of the `Stream`'s listeners synchronously.  In other words, after adding an event to your `Stream`, allow Dart to return the event loop so that the `Stream`'s listeners can execute:

  ```dart
  test('Stream listen test', () async {
    ...

    StreamListener subject = StreamListener(auth: mockAuth);
    controller.add(value);

    await Future<void>.value();
    expect(subject.state, LoginState.loggedIn);
  ```
- Since you are using a broadcast `Stream`, you alternatively could rely on multiple `Stream` listeners firing in order of registration. (I don't see any formal documentation guaranteeing that ordering, but I think it is the sanest behavior.) Your test could register its own listener after your object has registered its listener, use [`expectAsync1`](https://pub.dev/documentation/test_api/latest/expect/expectAsync1.html) to verify that the test's listener is called, and have the test's listener verify the state of your object:

  ```dart
  StreamListener subject = StreamListener(auth: mockAuth);

  controller.stream.listen(expectAsync1((event) {
    expect(event, value);
    expect(subject.state, LoginState.loggedIn);
  }));

  controller.add(value);
  ```
- Or combine the approaches:

  ```dart
  test('Stream listen test', () async {
    ...
    var eventReceived = Completer<void>();
    StreamListener subject = StreamListener(auth: mockAuth);

    controller.stream.listen((_) => eventReceived.complete());

    controller.add(value);

    await eventReceived.future;
    expect(subject.state, LoginState.loggedIn);
  ```